# References to Removed Framework in project.pbxproj File

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, pbxproj

I recently removed a framework from my iOS project and am installing it instead through a dependency manager (CocoaPods).  I noticed, however, when checking my changes in to source control that some references to the framework were removed, but one was added with an absolute path.  From the diff (the first line was removed and the second line added to my project file):

```
-       767C7EC51DB295CE00A8850F /* TealiumIOSLifecycle.framework */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = wrapper.framework; path = TealiumIOSLifecycle.framework; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
+       767C7EC51DB295CE00A8850F /* TealiumIOSLifecycle.framework */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = wrapper.framework; name = TealiumIOSLifecycle.framework; path = /Users/jal/workspace/com.myapp/MyApp/Shared/ThirdParty/TealiumIOSLifecycle.framework; sourceTree = "<absolute>"; };
```

There is no file at that path on my local machine, and I was able to make a fresh clone in a separate directory and on other machines with a different directory structure and was able to build the project without any warnings or errors.  The physical file of the framework no longer exists in the project directory (when I removed the file from the project in Xcode, I chose "move to trash).

Is this normal?  If not, how can I remove these references?

To be clear, there are no references to this framework anywhere in the project.  This includes Linked Frameworks and Libraries, Link Binary with Libraries, Target Dependencies, Embed Frameworks, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tap on your project file in xcode and in the *General* tab scroll down and check that it is not included in the following sections

[image]

The missing frameworks would be probably highlighted in red (or faded in gray i don't remember exactly)

Also in the build phases check it's not being tried to be copied

Comment: There are no references to the framework anywhere in the project.  This includes Linked Frameworks and Libraries, Link Binary with Libraries, Target Dependencies, Embed Frameworks, etc.  I will edit my question to make this clearer

Comment: I didn't look close enough, in one of my targets the framework was still there but it wasn't red.  I missed it in the long list under "Link Binary With Libraries."  Thanks!!

Comment: Happy to help. It tricked me so many times now it's always the first spot where i look for after any linking issue.

Comment: we have same avatars :D