# Runing xctests from Xcode and xcodebuild fails if simulator used - dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib issue - print()

Tags: swift, xcode, cordova, xcodebuild

I have experienced a strange behaviour, when I run the tests from Xcode or I execute this command from terminal:

```
xcodebuild test -scheme '<MY_APP>'
```

the tests are succeed in both cases although in the second case tests are successful, however I need to specify a test device obviously. When I try to do that and execute the same command with the -destination flag:

```
xcodebuild test -scheme '<MY_APP>' -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone XS,OS=latest"
```

I get this error:

```
e2019-02-18 18:39:22.625 xcodebuild[36312:791798] Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=6 "Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8a38637410 {Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=5 "Test runner exited before starting test execution." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Test runner exited before starting test execution., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the result bundle at /Users/<MY_USER>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<MY_APP>/Logs/Test/<MY_APP>-2019.02.18_18-37-12-+0100.xcresult}}} Generating coverage data... Generated coverage report: /Users/<MY_USER>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<MY_APP>-fbdolvrdfafpjbenwwqzgnlfkpoa/Logs/Test/Test-<MY_APP>.02.18_18-37-12-+0100.xcresult/1_Test/action.xccovreport Testing failed: <MY_APP>.app (36589) encountered an error (Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted. (Underlying error: Test runner exited before starting test execution.)) ** TEST FAILED **
```

Other things to mention: This is a Cordova application. The native iOS part is written in Objective-C. But I am using some libraries which are written in Swift. I need xcodebuild for testing the application on my server. Any suggestion what could cause this issue? Also for the first time when I execute the command without the destination flag codesigning is successful, but when I did it with the destination flag it is empty:

```
    CodeSign /Users/<MY_USER>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<MY_APP>-fbdolvrdfafpjbenwwqzgnlfkpoa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<MY_APP>.app/PlugIns/<MY_APP>Tests.xctest (in target: <MY_APP>Tests)
    cd /Users/<MY_USER>/projects/my_project/
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate

Signing Identity:     "-"
```

**UPDATE:**

Somehow I could get the cause of the problem, which is this well known error:

```
    dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/<MY_USER>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5AEAA313-0C65-49D8-BC20-DCC9994719C4/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/48DC52C0-4BC6-45ED-9AEE-A0E1F5C8BA1B/P2P-1-<MY_APP>.app/Frameworks/<REQUIRED_FRAMEWORK>.framework/<REQUIRED_FRAMEWORK>
```

You might think that from this point on the solution was is easy and straight forward, but it was not.

Comment: http://www.openradar.appspot.com/27260158 is a similar issue... turns out that this has nothing to do with signing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this library loading error pointed to a framework I was stucked...

I tried these: 
[dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40986082/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftswiftononesupport-dylib)

[Xcode - Bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720234/xcode-bundle-format-unrecognized-invalid-or-unsuitable)

[References to Removed Framework in project.pbxproj File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287250/references-to-removed-framework-in-project-pbxproj-file)

The `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` has set to `YES` in the app, but I am not sure wether it has set to `YES` in the given framework as well.

All in all the solution was from this question: [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40986082/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftswiftononesupport-dylib)

where LuisCien suggesting to specifically use `print()` anywhere in the code will somehow force `libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib` to be loaded and the issue will go away.

Tests are now running although I am very curious why this ,,hack,, works.

Also tests are only fails when I try to run it with simulator with Xcode or with xcodebuild.